# std::list implementation & pointer arithemetic.

Tags: c++, stdvector, allocation, doubly-linked-list, stdlist

As I understand it, std::vector allocates/de-allocates all the memory it requires each time it's elements grows or shrinks, therefore pointer arithmetic can be used to iterate the vector elements.

std::list on the other hand uses a double linked list, with each element pointing to the next and previous element.

Assuming(possibly wrongly) that std::list allocates it's memory dynamically, so memory is allocated, if and when required, incrementally.  How is  std::list still able to offer pointer arithmetic as a means to iterate it's elements?.

Comment: `std::list` doesn't provide pointer arithmetic for iteration.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you think `std::list` allows?

Comment: begin() returns an iter, so I'm assuming I can use operators like iter++ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: An `std::list`'s iterators can only be incremented or decremented in single steps. You cannot say `it += 5` or `it + 42`. That is what I meant in my first comment, which I realise wasn't completely clear. But neither is your question.

Comment: Is std::list not using pointer arithmetic when incrementing++ or decrementing-- its iterator in single steps?

Comment: Elements of `std::list` have pointers to the previous and to the next element.  An operator increment `it++` moves it to the next element by using those pointers.  It is just a pointer assignment, no arithmetic is actually happening.

Comment: std::list iterators have a std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, hence no arithmetic, just increment/derement

Comment: IMO. Just try to write down a simple list class and have an iterator for it. Then you can realize when implementing ++ operators you actually to something like pointer assignment. Pointer arithmetic works in situations where you can access memory as a contiguous  block. In a list you have buckets allocated with operation system specific memory allocation algorithm (not necessary to be contiguous ) in your program memory segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, you can assume an `std::list::iterator` to be a container for pointer to a list element `struct iterator { list::element *current };`.  And an element has pointers to the next and previous, like `struct element { list::element *next, *previous };` When you increment that iterator, it just reassigns this pointer to point to the next element.  Like `it->current = it->current->next` in linked lists.  No pointer arithmetics involved.

Comment: @tuk It isn't a pointer. What is the point is assuming it is?

Comment: I tried to implement my own version of std::list to do what you describe, however when I attempt to  increment the iterator using: iter++ it ignores my special list operator++ function and instead tries to use pointer arithmetic....because iterator is a pointer.  The only way I can get it working is by incrementing the list object itself so my operator++ function gets called.

Comment: Iterator is _not_ a pointer.

In my example, iterator is a structure and you have to override `operator++` for it as described.  Operator is redefined for the _iterator_, not for the list or list element.

Comment: I created a structure `iterator` that encapsulates a pointer intentionally.  Because I needed different behavior for `operator++` as default behavior for primitive types may not be changed.

Comment: @tuk  I agree with ftynse. Iterator is NOT a pointer. It's a placeholder to an element of your data structure object. iterator for a vector and list have internal implementation differentiation. Internally they may use pointers (specially in case of a list). But iterator itself is not a pointer. It's an other object with special purpose. It's better show your implementation, we you can have more fruitful comments.

Comment: Following on from ftynse's suggestions, how to resolve the dereferencing of the *iterator ? As a struct can't return a value!

Comment: @tuk, you may overload `operator *()`