# Implementing a list iterator and operators: -- ++ *

Tags: c++, list, iterator, operators, dereference

Following on from this question: [std::list implementation & pointer arithemetic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463343/stdlist-implementation-pointer-arithemetic)

I want to implement a list iterator that is interchangeable with other common containers types and their respective iterators, so I want to use operators such as: --, ++, * and be able to declare iterators as normal, so: **list::iterator iter = list.begin();**

The --, ++ operators now work as they should, but I ran up against the problem of de-referencing the iterator, as structs can't return a value: **T iterator::operator*()**

```
template <class T> 
struct element {

  element<T> *prev = NULL;
  element<T> *next = NULL;
  T data;       
};


template <typename T>
class list {

public:

    list::list();

    element<T>* current;

    struct iterator{

        element<T>* iterator::operator++(){ 

           this = *this->next; ..whatever it works          
        }
        element<T>* iterator::operator--()
        T iterator::operator*()
   }    
};
```

Comment: You'll want `operator*` to return a *reference*, or code like `*i = 0` will try to assign to a temporary copy.

Comment: `operator++` and `operator--` should return `iterator&`.

Comment: @Barry does it matter if what is being returned isn't used, see edit!

Comment: What about postfix `++` and `--` operators?

Comment: And *what* problem do you have with the dereference operator (besides it returning a value and not a reference)?

Comment: @Joachim they both appear to work without issue. If I change T* to T I get: Error 1 error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

Comment: Well you don't overload the postfix increase/decrement operators, just the prefix. And I'm surprised they work well since if they are as you show in the code snippet using them might lead to undefined behavior. (Hint: Should they not *return* something)?

Comment: Are you getting a *specific error*?  "structs can't return a value" isn't clear, which I think is why people are just pointing out arbitrary mistakes.

Comment: Also, I think the major problem here is that you handle *pointers* to the iterator, but you should handle *values* of the iterator, i.e. actual iterator instances.

Comment: Can you post the *real code*?

Comment: That is the real code Barry, I've been staring at this for days so forgive the rror, I've edited the body of ++ but really we're going off topic as both -- ++ work, its de-referencing the *iterator to get the value thats the question being asked?

Comment: Just to clear one thing up; there are **NO** restrictions what a function can return that stems from it being a part of a struct. If a regular function or a class function can return it, structs are good to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the iterators could look something like this:
(declared inside the list template)

```
    struct iterator;
    struct const_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, const T>
    {
        const_iterator() = default;
        T operator*() { return itm->data; }
        const T* operator->() { return &(itm->data); }
        const_iterator operator++() { itm = itm->next; return *this; }
        const_iterator operator--() { itm = itm->prev; return *this; }
        const_iterator operator++(int) { const_iterator ret=*this; itm = itm->next; return ret; }
        const_iterator operator--(int) { const_iterator ret=*this; itm = itm->prev; return ret; }
        bool operator==(const_iterator oth) const { return itm==oth.itm; }
        bool operator!=(const_iterator oth) const { return itm!=oth.itm; }
    private:
        element<T>* itm = nullptr;
        const_iterator(element<T>* i) : itm(i) {}
    friend
        class list;
    friend
        struct iterator;
    };
    struct iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>
    {
        iterator() = default;
        T& operator*() { return itm->data; }
        T* operator->() { return &(itm->data); }
        iterator operator++() { itm = itm->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator--() { itm = itm->prev; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { iterator ret=*this; itm = itm->next; return ret; }
        iterator operator--(int) { iterator ret=*this; itm = itm->prev; return ret; }
        bool operator==(iterator oth) const { return itm==oth.itm; }
        bool operator!=(iterator oth) const { return itm!=oth.itm; }
        operator const_iterator() { return {itm}; }
    private:
        element<T>* itm = nullptr;
        iterator(element<T>* i) : itm(i) {}
    friend
        class list;
    };

    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
```

this needs

```
#include <iterator>
```

to compile

Comment: while you're about it, make sure you use a sentry node. see http://pastebin.com/egDECvDi